# Format store the user's language by browser

Tags: javascript, string

I first check the navigator.languages array for its first element.

Then I get either navigator.userLanguage or navigator.language.

If this fails we get navigator.browserLanguage.

```
const getNavigatorLanguage = () =>
  (navigator.languages && navigator.languages.length) ?
    navigator.languages[0] :
    navigator.userLanguage ||
      navigator.language ||
      navigator.browserLanguage
```

I can get the result depending on the location in the format: `en-US`, `fr-FR`, `pl-PL`, `es-ES`. Is it possible to get the result in the format: `en`, `fr`, `pl`, `es`?
Without `US`,`FR`, `PL`,`ES`

Comment: Sure.  Do some research on `substring`.

Comment: `const xx = getNavigatorLanguage().split('-')[0]; // 'en', 'fr', ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically three ways to do this. Split on a hyphen `-` and get the first element of the array:

```
const [res] = getNavigatorLanguage().split("-");
```

Use a regex:

```
const [, res] = getNavigatorLanguage().match(/(\w*?)-/);
```

Or use `substring`:

```
const res = getNavigatorLanguage.substring(0, 2);
```

Comment: You don't need `indexOf` in the `substring` case, since all language codes are two letters.

Comment: Interesting - thanks @HereticMonkey!